# Integer to Float thorws TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found

Tags: python, serialization

I am trying to convert a float number to long and back just to see how to send it via sockets. I made the FloatToInt method just to test that number that I can't deserialize.
When converting it from float to long it works fine, but when I try to convert it from long to float again it throws "Non-hex digit found"

```
def FloatToInt(num):
    num = 22083.60066068796
    print "FloatToInt:float:%.10f" %num 
    packed = struct.pack('!f', num)
    print 'FloatToInt:Packed: %s' % repr(packed)
    integers = [ord(c) for c in packed]
    print 'FloatToInt:Integers: %s' % repr(integers)
    val = int(0)
    for i in integers:
        val |= i
        val = val << 8
    return val

def IntToFloat(num):
    #val = struct.unpack('!f', num.decode('hex'))[0]
    #return val
    intArr = []
    while num > 0:
        val = num & 0xFF
        if val > 0:
            intArr.append(int(val))
        num = num >> 8
    print 'IntToFloat:Integers: %s' % repr(intArr)
    chars = [chr(c) for c in intArr]
    str = ""
    for ch in chars:
        str += ch
    print 'IntToFloat:Hex chars: %s' % repr(str)
    ret = struct.unpack('!f', str.decode('hex'))[0]
    return ret
```

This outputs:

> FloatToInt:float:22083.6006606880
>   FloatToInt:Packed: 'F\xac\x874'
>   FloatToInt:Integers: [70, 172, 135, 52]
>   IntToFloat:Integers: [52, 135, 172, 70]
>   IntToFloat:Hex chars: '4\x87\xacF'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ........
>   TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found

So str.decode('hex') throws an error, although I have the same integer values as when I packed the values in the FloatToInt method.
Do you have any ideea what I'm missing?
Thank you

Comment: Do you understand what the "hex" codec does?

Comment: Decodes the obj using the 'hex'(2 bytes) codec registered for encoding?!

Comment: But do you *understand* what that means?

Comment: ` '4\x87\xacF'` is not hex string - it is standard text and you see some chars as its nex code because `repr` do this. This is hex string `'0487AC0F'` - it uses only chars `0-9` and `A-F` and every 2 chars describe one number and you see it without `repr`.

Comment: there is no need to convert `pack()` result to long integer to send via socket. For socket this long int is only 4 bytes - the same like `pack()` result.

Comment: you don't have to use `.decode('hex')` to unpack string. But you have to reverse elements in intArr to get correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode('hex')` is use to decode strings like this `'0487AC0F'`.

```
print( '0487AC0F'.decode('hex') )
```

But you don't need `decode()` in your code. You have to only reverse elements in `intArr` to get correct result.

BTW. to send `float` via socket you need only `pack`/`unpack` - you don't have to create `long int` - because socket can send only string or rather bytes. To send `long int` via socket you will need `pack`/`unpack` to convert it into string/bytes.

```
import struct

def FloatToInt(num):
    num = 22083.60066068796
    print "FloatToInt:float:%.10f" %num

    packed = struct.pack('!f', num)
    print 'FloatToInt:Packed: %s' % repr(packed)

    integers = [ord(c) for c in packed]
    print 'FloatToInt:Integers: %s' % repr(integers)

    val = int(0)
    for i in integers:
        val |= i
        val = val << 8

    return val

def IntToFloat(num):
    intArr = []

    while num > 0:
        val = num & 0xFF
        if val > 0:
            intArr.append(val)
        num = num >> 8

    # you have to reverse numbers
    intArr = list(reversed(intArr))

    print 'IntToFloat:Integers: %s' % repr(intArr)

    text = "".join([chr(c) for c in intArr])
    #chars = [chr(c) for c in intArr]
    #text = ""
    #for ch in chars:
    #    text += ch

    print 'IntToFloat:Hex chars: %s' % repr(text)

    # you don't need decode('hex')
    ret = struct.unpack('!f', text)[0]

    return ret

num = 22083.60066068796
r = FloatToInt(num)
print '   FloatToInt:', r 
r = IntToFloat(r) 
print '   IntToFloat:', r
```

---

**EDIT:** Python uses CPU float but it has two types

- single precision - called "float"
- double precision - called "double"

It seams Python use "double" in this example so you can use `!d` instead of `!f` to get correct value

```
import struct

num = 22083.60066068796
print "   float: %.10f" % num

packed = struct.pack('!d', num)
print '  packed: %s' % repr(packed)

ret = struct.unpack('!d', packed)[0]
print "unpacked: %.10f" %num
```

.

```
   float: 22083.6006606880
  packed: '@\xd5\x90\xe6q9\x86\xb2'
unpacked: 22083.6006606880
```

`"double"` in previous code

```
 import struct

def FloatToInt(num):

    print "FloatToInt:    float: %.10f" % num

    packed = struct.pack('!d', num)
    print 'FloatToInt:   Packed: %s' % repr(packed)

    integers = [ord(c) for c in packed]
    print 'FloatToInt: Integers: %s' % integers

    val = int(0)
    for i in integers:
        val |= i
        val = val << 8

    print 'FloatToInt:   result: %d\n' % val

    return val

def IntToFloat(num):

    print 'IntToFloat:  integer: %d\n' % num

    intArr = []

    while num > 0:
        val = num & 0xFF
        if val > 0:
            intArr.append(val)
        num = num >> 8

    intArr = list(reversed(intArr))

    print 'IntToFloat: Integers: %s' % intArr

    text = "".join([chr(c) for c in intArr])
    print 'IntToFloat:Hex chars: %s' % repr(text)

    ret = struct.unpack('!d', text)[0]
    print 'IntToFloat:   result: %.10f\n' % ret

    return ret

num = 22083.60066068796
r = FloatToInt(num)
r = IntToFloat(r)
```

.

```
FloatToInt:    float: 22083.6006606880
FloatToInt:   Packed: '@\xd5\x90\xe6q9\x86\xb2'
FloatToInt: Integers: [64, 213, 144, 230, 113, 57, 134, 178]
FloatToInt:   result: 1195980674018107109888

IntToFloat:  integer: 1195980674018107109888
IntToFloat: Integers: [64L, 213L, 144L, 230L, 113L, 57L, 134L, 178L]
IntToFloat:Hex chars: '@\xd5\x90\xe6q9\x86\xb2'
IntToFloat:   result: 22083.6006606880
```

Comment: The only issue here is that I am packing a .10f, so a 10 decimals float and I am unpacking a slight different 7 decimals float. So, I am packing this: 22083.60066068796 and unpacking 22083.6015625

Comment: you doesn't pack `.10f` - `.10f` is used only to format text on screen. Use `.10f` to display result and probably you get correct text.

Comment: If I print it like: print "%.10f" %ret I will get: 22083.6015625000 so it's rounded. I need to pack it and unpack it correctly, I am working with high precision voltage mesurements.

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to send it via socket, like convert it to decimal number by multiplying with 10^11 and send it, and on the other side de-convert it. But the idea is that I am getting this from some sensors via socket and I cannot change how the data is packed, I just need un unpack it.

Comment: CPU has two types of float: sungle precision ("float") and double precision ("double") - use `"!d"` instead of `"!f"` to get correct result. See new code in answer.